# How can i count number of records in last 30 days for each user per row in pyspark?

Tags: sql, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataset with a sample fragment below.How can I fill the `recordcounts_in_last_30_days` with a count of number of records in last 30 days for each user per row like this:

| date | userid | comment | recordcounts_in_last_30_days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-15 09:00 | 1 | examplecomment1 | 0 |
| 2022-01-16 09:00 | 2 | examplecomment2 | 0 |
| 2022-01-25 09:00 | 1 | examplecomment3 | 1 |
| 2022-01-28 09:00 | 2 | examplecomment3 | 1 |
| 2022-02-26 09:00 | 2 | examplecomment3 | 1 |
| 2022-03-25 09:00 | 1 | examplecomment4 | 0 |

Please write in the comments if you don't understand the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `count` over a window bounded with [`rangeBetween`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Window.rangeBetween.html) like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w = (Window.partitionBy("userid").orderBy(F.col("date").cast("long"))
     .rangeBetween(-30 * 86400, -1) # 86400 = number of second in a day
     )

result = (df.withColumn("date", F.to_timestamp("date", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"))
          .withColumn("recordcounts_in_last_30_days", F.count("*").over(w))
          )

result.show()
#+-------------------+------+---------------+----------------------------+
#|               date|userid|        comment|recordcounts_in_last_30_days|
#+-------------------+------+---------------+----------------------------+
#|2022-01-15 09:00:00|     1|examplecomment1|                           0|
#|2022-01-25 09:00:00|     1|examplecomment3|                           1|
#|2022-03-25 09:00:00|     1|examplecomment4|                           0|
#|2022-01-16 09:00:00|     2|examplecomment2|                           0|
#|2022-01-28 09:00:00|     2|examplecomment3|                           1|
#|2022-02-26 09:00:00|     2|examplecomment3|                           1|
#+-------------------+------+---------------+----------------------------+
```